# Does adding many css classes to an element lead to any performance impact?

Tags: css, performance-testing, web-performance

In our project we have base css file which contains classes for most of the common css properties (like `.p10` -> `padding:10px`, `vam` -> `vertical-align:middle`).

If I use many of these classes in a single DOM, does it lead to any performance impact?

Comment: None whatsoever. You're still doing it wrong.

Comment: What is wrong ? can you please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding 7 bytes of HTML, this is effectively 0 impact on your site, and the CSS processes that so fast again, effectively 0 impact on your site.

There are plenty of CSS frameworks that utilize a modular approach like that, and your code may look something like this:

```
<main>
  <div class="p10 vam d_ib blk internal bigshadow"></div>
  <div class="p10 vam d_ib blk internal bigshadow"></div>
  <div class="p10_20 vam d_ib blk accent-blue internal bigshadow"></div>
</main>

.p10 { padding: 10px; }
.p10_20 { padding: 10px 20px; }
.vam { vertical-align: middle; }
.d_ib { display: inline-block; }
.internal { background: #fff; }
.blk { color: #000; }
.bigshadow { box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.5); }
```

Without using a framework, (or developing an internal one) you may want something a little less modular, and more element oriented:

```
<main>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container accent"></div>
</main>
```

with the accompanying CSS:

```
/* This or main > div */
main .container {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.container.accent {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 2px solid #0095ee;
}
```

To reiterate an answer to the question at hand, there is effectively **zero** impact of stacking classes on elements.

Comment: _"this isn't really the appropriate way to go about CSS"_ -

A lot of people would disagree with this. See Utility First CSS/Atomic CSS/Functional CSS and frameworks like TailwindCSS - as well as sites like GitHub, Twitch, Kickstarter and many more.

Answer (score 2):

It does not lead to any performance impact (it may be even faster than constructing deeply nested selectors).

Moreover, the method that you are asking about has even its own name - **atomic css** and apart from what @Xhynk said it is not always that bad as it allows for easy customization and is widely used in many CSS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this kind of notation doesn't have impact on the speed of processing such monstrosity, there is a **massive** impact in terms of readability. It's not going to be long before you start having lines that span more than 160 characters. Been there, seen it, didn't do it, and you shouldn't do it either because readability of such code suffers too much. Imagine having 10 `div`s one by line with 200+ characters describing how you want the to look. It completely overshadows the structure of your HTML and makes it really hard to maintain such a beast.

Atomic CSS used with `@apply` with TailwindCSS nad PostCSS for empty/unused classes elimination is the way to go. If you would like to learn more about it, I have a repository that shows the problem:

https://github.com/padcom/tailwind-example/blob/inline-apply-cmp/src/App.vue

vs

https://github.com/padcom/tailwind-example/blob/master/src/App.vue

There's also been a concern regarding the size of produced output. [README.md](https://github.com/padcom/tailwind-example/blob/inline-apply-cmp/README.md) shows the comparison between different styles and compression methods. As it was to be expected, the compressed size (so the way it will actually be transferred over the wire) with `@apply` instead of inlining all the classes rules in favor of using cleaner code.